# How to extend an 2-d Array?

Tags: swift

Say I got an array like this

```
let a = [['1', '2', '3']]
```

I would like to add a function for this specifc type of array

```
extension Array where Element == Array {

  func value(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Any? { // How to use generic type here
      guard self.count > indexPath.section, self[indexPath.section].count > indexPath.row else { return nil }
      return self[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
  }
}
```

However, its obvious that the condition is recursive.

Anyone has idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can constrain your collection elements to conform to `Collection`. Regarding your question "How to use generic?" collection `Element` is already generic, therefore In your method you just need to return the `Element.Element` instead of `Any`.

If really you want to use `IndexPath` in your method signature you need to constrain your collection's  `Index` and sub collection `Elements.Index` to `Int`:

```
extension Collection where Element: Collection, Index == Int, Element.Index == Int {
    func value(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Element.Element? {
        guard indices.contains(indexPath.section),
              self[indexPath.section].indices.contains(indexPath.row)
        else { return nil }
        return self[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let a = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]]
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 1)
a.value(at: indexPath)  // "6"
```

---

If you want to make your method more generic to work wit any kind of collection you need to remove the restriction of `Int` indices:

```
extension Collection where Element: Collection {
    func value(at index: Index, subIndex: Element.Index) -> Element.Element? {
        guard indices.contains(index),
              self[index].indices.contains(subIndex)
        else { return nil }
        return self[index][subIndex]
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let stringA = "123"
let stringB = "456"
let subIndex = stringB.index(stringB.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
let b = ["123","456"]
b.value(at: 1, subIndex: subIndex)  // "6"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go with a more compile type safety construct here, like making it clear you cannot pass more than two indexes.

For this, you can move the generics constraints to the function definition, this will give you more control over the generics:

```
extension Array {
    subscript<T>(index1: Index, index2: Index) -> T where Element == [T] {
        return self[index1][index2]
    } 
}
```

Usage:

```swift
print(a[0, 1]) // 2
```

Note that above you have the non-optional variant, an optional, "safe" one is easy to build:

```swift
extension Array {    
    subscript<T>(maybe index1: Index, index2: Index) -> T? where Element == [T] {
        guard index1 < endIndex, index2 < self[index1].endIndex else { return nil }
        return self[index1, index2]
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
print(a[maybe: 0, 1]) // Optional("2")
```

If you really want, you can also build on top of these an `IndexPath` overload, the only problem I have with that type is that it doesn't transmit at compile time enough information about the number of indexes it holds: what if it has 3 indexes, should you return nil, or consider only the first two? Too much runtime uncertainty :) This is why I also recommend the non-optional one, basically if you end up unwrapping the optional why better not checking the indexes upfront?